# My website is blocked by a firewall

Tags: https, firewall

Some big compagnies blocked my website by with their firewall. I don't know if I can do something for that. Will it be better If I use a self signed certificate rather than one signed by amazon ? What can be the issue of my website ? I have no idea.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). How does  *big companies are blacklisting my website* qualify as a programming related question? Contact the companies and ask them why they're blocking you, and then fix your site so they no longer feel the need to do so. We can't tell you what the issue is with your site. (And no, a self-signed certificate isn't going to improve things. Big companies will find no value in a  certificate you've signed yourself, because anyone can sign their own cert, including malware authors.)

Comment: @kenWhite Thank.s for your answer. I thought it was a common issue. I will try to ask them

Comment: "Big companies" will never see your certificate. Or small companies. All the major browsers refuse to connect to https sites that present self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly not personal. Big companies don't "dislike" your website, they probably don't even know it exists.

If you have a self-signed certificate, your site is being blocked by the major browsers because the certificate is invalid, not by any particular company.

The point of an SSL certificate is that it's traceable back to a trusted certification authority. A self-signed certificate is *not* from a trusted certification authority and will be trusted by nobody and blocked or at least warned about by all standards-compliant browsers.

If you have a self signed cert, the first thing you should do is get a real one.

If you're on a shared IP address, it's probably being blocked by a rule in a network appliance that is blocking the entire IP, not just your site. It's the internet equivalent of "living in a bad neighborhood and not being able to get pizza delivered". The problem isn't you; it's your some of your neighbors.

Get a real SSL cert. Then if you're still having problems, move your site to a "better neighborhood" (a better hosting provider).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. actually, I'm not on a shared Ip address and I get my ssl from aws. I found the problem. I got in touch with the IT department of this big compagnies and it's because my website is not categorized in their firewall

Comment: @KevinVincent I'm also using aws and seem to be getting blocked by firewalls... can you elaborate on the issue you found with yours?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't an AWS issue, big compagnies are using firewall to filter "useless" website. I just ask one of them the name of their firewall then I contacted them to ask them to put me on the white list